# Change font/color for a field in django admin interface if expression is True

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

In change list view in django admin interface, is it possible to mark some fields/rows red in  if they achieve a expression?

For example, if there is a model `Group` with `members` and `capacity`, how can I visualize when they are *full* or *crowded*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an old question but I'll add an example from docs for `Django 1.10` because `allow_tags` attribute used in the accepted answer is deprecated since `Django 1.9` and it is recommended to use [format_html](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/utils/#django.utils.html.format_html) instead:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin
from django.utils.html import format_html

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    color_code = models.CharField(max_length=6)

    def colored_name(self):
        return format_html(
            '<span style="color: #{};">{} {}</span>',
            self.color_code,
            self.first_name,
            self.last_name,
        )

class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'colored_name')
```

Answer (score 11):

For modifying how and what is displayed in change list view, one can use [`list_display`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display) option of [`ModelAdmin`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-objects).

Mind you, columns given in `list_display` that are not real database fields can not be used for sorting, so one needs to give Django admin a hint about which database field to actually use for sorting.

One does this by setting `admin_order_field` attribute to the callable used to wrap some value in HTML for example.

Example from Django docs for colorful fields:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    color_code = models.CharField(max_length=6)

    def colored_first_name(self):
        return '<span style="color: #%s;">%s</span>' % (
                             self.color_code, self.first_name)
    colored_first_name.allow_tags = True
    colored_first_name.admin_order_field = 'first_name'

class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('first_name', 'colored_first_name')
```

I hope some of this helps.

Comment: Thank you, .allow_tags did the job.

Comment: Great answer @rebus. Is there anyway to bind the `colored_first_name` function and attrs to the `PersonAdmin` as opposed to the model? It seems odd to specify admin specific attrs to the model.

Comment: @cooncesean Yes, the value of list_display can either be a string name of method on the model or the admin class, or it can be a reference to a callable. [Check out the docs for more examples](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display)

Comment: `allow_tags` attribute is deprecated starting from `Django 1.9` and I added a separate answer with an example using `format_html` method

Answer (score 2):

In addition you can use

```
colored_first_name.short_description = 'first name'
```

For a nice column title