# django: change color of row for special value in admin interface

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-templates

I want to change a row color/column color when a special value is calculated for one of admin list_display parameter in the admin site. 
I am a Django newbie.
I don't know how to hack the admin interface.I managed this problem for my own app as follows:
I write a function for calculating a balanced time which returns a timedelta value:

**models.py**

```
def balanced_time(self):
    t = self.gew_zeit - datetime.now()
    ...
    return timedelta(t.days, t.seconds, 0)
```

and check the condition for the color with a color function:

```
def color():
    return gew_zeit - datetime.now() > timedelta(0, 18000, 0)
```

For the validation of the balanced_time value I render this **app.html** template table:

```
<table summary="This is one table from a database">

    <caption>table entries of a model</caption>

    <thead>

        <tr>
            <th align="left" scope="col">Count</th>
            <th align="left" scope="col">Balanced Time</th>

        </tr>

    </thead>

    <tbody>

    {% if order_items %}

        {% for item in order_items %}

            <tr>
                <td align="left" >{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
                {% if item.color %}
                    <td>{{ item.balanced_time }}</td>
                {% else %}
                    <td style="color:#ff0000;" >{{ item.balanced_time }}</td>
                {% endif %}

            </tr>

        {% endfor %}

    {% endif %}

    </tbody>

</table>
```

Now the text in the column balanced_time is colored red, when its balanced_time is < 5 hours.
All this works fine, but I don't know how to transfer this behaviour to the admin change_list_results.html template, or is there another more efficient way to manage this for the admin site.
I also found the following [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442881/change-font-color-for-a-field-in-django-admin-interface-if-expression-is-true), as well as this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014914/change-row-colour-in-django-admin-list). But they do not work for me. Perhaps I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Is there anyone out there, who can help?