# django-admin: change column font to red when if condition is true

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a vlog that I can preload vlog entries into the db, so that when the date of `vlog-published-date` is less than the models field of `now`, the vlog entry will be automatically displayed / published.

How can I make the django-admin column of `Vlog Date Published` font red when the date of the `vlog_published_date` is greater than `now` (not yet published)?

Here is a visual example of what I mean where the `now` date is **January 16, 2018**:

[image]

Here is my vlog models.py code:

```
class VlogDetails(models.Model):
    ....
    vlog_date_published = models.DateField(null=False, blank=False, default=datetime.now, help_text='The date the vlog video will be made public.')
    ....

    class Meta:
        ....
```

There is this [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442881/change-font-color-for-a-field-in-django-admin-interface-if-expression-is-true), but the thread is 7+ years old and I was hoping there was information more current to django 1.10 and python 3.5.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16410957/allow-tags-true-does-not-render-form-tag-in-django-admin/16411101#16411101

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the answer - I hope that this helps somone!

This is my **models.py** code:

```
class VlogDetails(models.Model):
    ....
    vlog_date_published = models.DateField(null=False, blank=False, default=datetime.now, help_text='The date the vlog video will be made public.')
    ....

    # date published replaces vlog_date_published in the admin - displays red date when vlog not published.
    def date_published(self):
        if self.vlog_date_published > datetime.today().date():
            return format_html('<span style="color: #cc0033; font-weight: bold;">{0}</span>', self.vlog_date_published.strftime('%b. %d, %Y'))
        else:
            return format_html('<span style="color: #000;">{0}</span>', self.vlog_date_published.strftime('%b. %d, %Y'))

    date_published.allow_tags = True

    class Meta:
        ....
```

Here is my **admin.py** code:

```
list_display = [
    u'id',
    #'vlog_date_published', # vlog_date_published now replaced by date_published.
    'date_published',
    'vlog_title',
    ....
]
```

This is the visual representation:

[image]

Comment: It might be good to include that `format_html` canbe imported with `from django.utils.html import format_html`